# How to remove specific number of bits from Serial Port received bytes

Tags: serial-port, bit-shift, bitmask

I have a data of about 128 bytes arriving at a serila port. I need to remove the first 3 bits of this data befor processing. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

All suggestion would be apreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the following information. Which of the 3 bits is the LSB or MSB of the first byte? What is the format of the remaining 5 bits and 127 bytes of data as a result of removing the 3 bits? For example, do you depend on endianness? What OS, programming language, library are you using, and what version is it?

Comment: @ kunif, many thanks for your response. I would like to have the information in both scenerios i.e. if the 3 bits is the LSB or MSB of the first byte. The format of the remaining 5 bits and 127 bytes of data as a result of removing the 3 bits is Hexadecimal. For the endianess, all possible scenerios will be welcome. OS: Win 7 X64. Programming language: Visual Studio 2013 - C#. Many thanks